# what' the simplest way to bind my grid view on one record(distinct different data)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, datarowview

What's the simplest way to bind my grid view to a single data row :

I have the following data for example :

```
dep_code = 3;
dep_name = "computer science";
boss_num = 356;
boss_name ="Ahmed";
```

i want to bind those data on my gridview.

Comment: What have you tried, what was the problem? Why do you need a `GridView` for a single record? You can use a `DetailsView` or `FormView`.

Comment: i have 4 values like the above , and i want to bind them on my grid view(one record) , can i use anonymous object or some way!! or i have to create a data table

Comment: I think the most easiest way is to create a `DataTable`. As your `GridView` probably has column headers to? Which can be defined in your `DataTable` as well.

Comment: @just_name: You can create a `DataTable` or an anonymous type, both approaches are pretty easy, so i don't understand the problem.

Comment: i ask about the most convenient way to bind one record .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think List of list should be simplest

```
List<List<string>> list = {{dep_code,dep_name,boss_num,boss_name}};
GridView1.DataSource = list;
GridView1.DataBind();
```